# Synchronize CoreData objects using a private key but keep the unique Object ID same for relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, entity-relationship, nsmanagedobject

This is the scenario:

I have a managedObject:

`Category`

With properties:

```
categoryId String
categoryName String
subCategory SubCategory
```

The `SubCategory` managedObject has properties:

```
categoryId String
categoryName String
categoryInverse Category
contractInverse Contract
```

The `Contract` managedObject has properties:

```
contractId String
contractName String
subCategoryInverse SubCategory
```

I get the Category and Sub-category data in JSON from the web service, and I then create Contracts that are tied to the Category and Sub-Category by means of inverse relationships.

The problem is, when I retrieve the fresh list of `Categories` and SubCategories from the server upon app launch, I delete the previous `Categories` and `SubCategories` and populate them with new data. This in turn breaks the relationship and the new `Contract` object has `nil` for the subCategory object which would have been my link to the `Category` object `(contract.subCategoryInverse.categoryInverse)`

How can I update the `Category`/`SubCategory` data without losing the existing relationships?

Comment: The obvious thing would be to not delete your existing objects, but to update them in place. Why do you delete everything on app launch?

Comment: Is there an easy way of updating the records rather than deleting all and adding the new objects? Especially when the server doesn't support any syncing strategies.

Comment: Fetch the existing records, change their values, and save changes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the update data from the server
2. Fetch all of your categories
3. Put them all in a dictionary with the categoryId as the key and the managedObject as the value.
4. Also put all of the categories managedObjects in a mutableSet `categoriesToDelete`.
5. Now go through your server data get the category by Id from the dictionary.  If it is not there then create it.  If it is there then remove it from `categoriesToDelete`and update it.
6. Delete all objects in `categoriesToDelete`
7. Do the same thing for subcategories